# How to have a textbox more than 20 pixels high?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi when I create a textbox on Visual studio on Windows Form Application, I can get the width more than 20 pixels, however I cannot get the **height** more than 20 pixels.

So how will I be able to resize height?

Comment: I tagged this as [Winforms]. If you use another technology (WPF?), please re-tag the question.

Comment: Repeated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853073/change-the-textbox-height

Comment: Then you have it somehow put in some kind of container. Is your Textbox in a TableLayoutPanel or something? Usually you should be able to just adjust the hight like the width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `Multiline` property to `true` in the designer, then you will be able to resize the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Multiline = true`, I can change the `height` portion of the `Size` property and the change sticks. The display area of the `Textbox` auto-sizes to the font selected, so you can set the higher font size to increase the size of the textbox, but you are not intend to it.

**Multiline = true**
In this mode the height of the text box can be of any value thus allowing different number of rows in it.

Ref:
[How-To set Height of a Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711017/how-to-set-height-of-a-textbox)
[TextBox cannot adjust height size](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/editors/textbox-cannot-adjust-height-size.aspx)

Edit: You can [customize the TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493843/how-to-override-the-preferred-size-of-a-winforms-textbox) also.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the [font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font.aspx) size.

If you're using WPF:

```
<TextBox Height="42"/>
```

Comment: I use Windows Form Application

Comment: ivowiblo's comment is not about the height, it is about the width. I want to change the height. So whenever I try to change it other than 20 it does not resize!

Comment: No, it's about the height. Check the title!

Comment: OK I Fixed it by changing Multiline thank you I thought it is something else( I mean your link, I think you've changed it)

Comment: You can't change the Height property of a Windows Forms TextBox control unless 1) You make it Multiline, 2) You increase the Font size, or 3) You roll your own custom control.